# How Can I Use a Single Codebase for Unreal and Unity 3D?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4

I have a codebase and plan to (eventually) make this available to third-parties as a game template on the Unity3D store. The core code is written in C# with some nUnit and Integration tests, again in C#.

So far, so good. Doesn't sound so bad, but...

Thinking ahead, I would like to make a similar game template available for Unreal which is C++. I don't wish to maintain two codebases in both C# and C++, that would be silly (and a recipe for distaster).

Instead, I'd like to consolidate all of my business logic in a single library/dll in *either* C++ or C#. I'm actually not bothered which one, but I'm swaying towards C++, with it's cross-platform properties. I'm not so scared of reqriting my C# code to C++ as it's all fairly modular and well-tested.

Assuming I take the C++ route, how would I handle interfaces (abstract classes in C++) on the C# side?

Comment: I don't think it's valid to make dlls for C++. You can make dlls for C. You can't guarantee binary compatibility between different C++ interfaces.

Comment: You will probably have a lot of problems if you want to publish classes as interfaces. There are no (at least no cross-platform widely accepted) conventions of how the classes are populated. You may make your logic interfaces purely procedural so you can create a library with functions that can be later invoked from managed C# code. IMHO it won't do any good though - the overhead is high enough to make the whole process not reasonable.

Comment: It would be much easier to maintain two separate projects since Unity and UE doesn't have anything in common. Also, when you implement logic to your codebase, it shoul be trivial to create C# / C++ equivalent.